# Spring Boot/Jersey Component Scan Issue

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jersey

I'm using Spring Boot and Jersey for a small app, and I need to add @ComponentScan to scan a third-party library for some services. The problem is, whenever I add the @ComponentScan annotation, it seems that the Spring MVC DispatcherServlet takes over, and I can no longer hit my Jersey endpoints (it doesn't look like the JerseyServlet is even loaded when I add the annotation). How do I get component scan to work alongside my Jersey endpoints?

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
  }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        packages("com.demo.rest.endpoint");

        register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_VERBOSITY, null));
    }
}
```

**Endpoint**

```
@Component
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint {
    @GET
    public String test() {
        return "Testing Jersey Endpoint";
    }
}
```

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` already defines a `@ComponentScan` that scans from the current directly recursively. Not sure, but your `@ComponentScan` might override that. Try to just define a `@Configuration` class and put your `@ComponentScan` on that class.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the issue. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem on how jersey scans classes on fatjars. Keep everything and add register each class on your JerseyConfig.

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
     [...]

     register(TestEndpoint.class);
}
```